# $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)$: where do we use independence property?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose both r.v. $X$ and $Y$ are defined on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$. Furthermore, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, in the sense that $\mathbb{P}\left(X\in B_1 \cap Y\in B_2\right)= \mathbb{P}\left(X\in B_1\right) \mathbb{P}\left(Y \in B_2\right)$. How do we show that $\mathbb{E}\left(XY\right) = \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)$?

Ideally I would like to use Fubini and product measure, but I have some confusions. Now, if we consider the product space $\left(\Omega^2, \mathcal{F}^2, \mathbb{P}^2\right)$, and we define a random variable $Z$ on it as $Z\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right)=X\left(\omega_1\right) Y\left(\omega_2\right)$, we do have

$$\int_{\Omega^2} Z \,d\mathbb{P}^2 = \int_\Omega X \,d\mathbb{P} \int_\Omega Y \,d\mathbb{P}$$

by Tonelli-Fubini (assuming necessary technical assumptions are satisfied). The r.v. $Z$ we just defined is just $XY$.

However here is my confusion: Where did we use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

**Update:** Here is the proof in the book.

[image]

Comment: $XY$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},{P})$ does not necessarily have the same distribution (nor expectation) as $Z$ on $(\Omega^2, \mathcal{F}^2,{P}^2)$ as you defined it without the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent - try to do the same thing with $X = -Y$, $X$ uniform on $[-1,1]$ say.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about the book's proof?  (In other words, how is the book's proof not a satisfactory answer to your question?)

Comment: @EricWofsey It wasn't clear to me how the proof uses independence, but I think I get it now. I thought we were applying Fubini on the abstract space $\Omega\times\Omega$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$...The book was talking about constructing abstract product space after this proof so I got confused... :)

Comment: The fact that $\mu^2(dx,dy) = \mu_1(dx) \mu_2(dy)$ is independence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation has nothing to do with the formula $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}X \mathbb{E}Y$. You have to show that

$$ \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)Y(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \left( \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) \right)\left( \int_{\Omega} Y(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) \right), $$

and you will desperately need the independence of $X$ and $Y$. As a proof, you may first consider the case where $X$ and $Y$ are simple, i.e.,

$$ X = \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \mathbf{1}_{A_1}, \qquad Y = \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j \mathbf{1}_{B_j} $$

for some constants $x_i, y_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and events $A_i \in \sigma(X)$ and $B_j \in \sigma(Y)$.

---

Here is a detail of the proof in the photo. Recall the following basic theorems.

**1. Change of variables formula.**

> **Theorem 1.** Suppose that
>
> - $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space,
> - $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is a measurable space,
> - $X : \Omega \to S$ is measurable.
>
> Denote by $\mu(E) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega:X(\omega)\in E\})$ the law of $X$. Then for any measurable map $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ X$ is either non-negative or integrable, we have
>
> $$ \mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) \, \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \int_{S} f(x) \, \mu(dx). $$

**2. Independence as factoring of the joint law.**

> **Theorem 2.** Let $X, Y$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables. Denote the law of $(X,Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ by
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mu_{X,Y}(E) &= \mathbb{P}(\{\omega : (X(\omega),Y(\omega))\in E\}), \\
> \mu_X(E) &= \mathbb{P}(\{\omega : X(\omega)\in E\}), \\
> \mu_Y(E) &= \mathbb{P}(\{\omega : Y(\omega)\in E\})
> \end{align*}
>
> Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
> 2. $\mu_{X,Y} = \mu_X \otimes \mu_Y$.

Now the proof goes as follows: Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $XY$ is integrable. Then writing $XY$ as the composition of $f(x, y) = xy$ and $(X, Y)$, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[XY]
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} xy \, \mu_{X,Y}(dxdy) \tag{$\because$ Theorem 1} \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} xy \, \mu_X(dx)\mu_Y(dy)\tag{$\because$ Theorem 2} \\
&= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, \mu_X(dx) \right)\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \, \mu_Y(dy) \right) \tag{$\because$ Fubini} \\
&= (\mathbb{E} X)(\mathbb{E} Y) \tag{$\because$ Theorem 1}
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe what I wrote is how my textbook proves $\mathbb{E}(XY) = E(X) E(Y)$, if I did not misunderstand anything. Can you see my update?

Comment: But I do feel unsure about what $XY$ exactly means. Seems like it makes sense to define it as a r.v. on $\Omega\times\Omega$, or to define it simply on $\Omega$, in which case we cannot talk about $X(\omega_1) Y(\omega_2)$ for different $\omega_1, \omega_2$...

Comment: @3x89g2, $XY$ is simply the pointwise product of two functions $X, Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e., it is a function $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(XY)(\omega) := X(\omega)Y(\omega)$.

Comment: OK. So I guess I had a misunderstanding. The proof in the book applies Fubini _not to_ the product space $\Omega\times\Omega$, but to $\mathbb{R}^2$...But it's still not clear to me where the independence come into play?

Comment: @3x89g2, And as for the proof of the textbook, it is totally sound. Notice that the factoring is not occurring on the sample space; rather it occurs at the target space. That is, If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then their joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ factors out. So the proof in the photo proceeds first by applying the change of variables formula to rewrite the expectation as an integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$ w.r.t. the joint distribution and then factors out the integral using independence.

Comment: Ah I see. That's the piece I skipped reading due to impatience... :( It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect, because $XY$ denotes the random variable $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ on $\Omega$, which is different from your random variable $Z(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ on $\Omega^2$.

The step where independence is used in the book's proof is when it uses "(3)" to say $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xy\mu^2(dx,dy)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^1} xy \mu_1(dx)\mu_2(dy).$$  What is being used in this step is the fact that the measure $\mu^2$ is the same as the product measure $\mu_1\times\mu_2$, which is exactly the definition of independence.  Indeed, $\mu^2$ is by definition the measure that sends a rectangle $B_1\times B_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{P}(X\in B_1\text{ and }Y\in B_2)$, whereas $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ is by definition the measure that sends $B_1\times B_2$ to $\mathbb{P}(X\in B_1)\mathbb{P}(Y\in B_2)$.